# How to make eclipselink perform better about bulk insert

Tags: performance, jpa, jdbc, eclipselink

I am testsing eclipselink to make bulk data insert into derby.
    Compared by the same set of data, eclipse link take double time of jdbc batch update.

```
I have enabled the batchupdate feature of eclipse link, and the other properties:

        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing" value="JDBC"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.batch-writing.size" value="1000"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.cache-statements" value="true"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.cache-statements.size" value="30"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.cache.shared.default" value="false"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.read-connections.max" value="20"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.read-connections.min" value="1"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.write-connections.min" value="1"/>
        <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.write-connections.max" value="30"/>
```

The question is how to make eclipse link be faster?

Answer (score 1):

Please include the code, and the SQL log.  Also include your JDBC code, and make sure it is kosher (closing statements, etc.).

Are you using sequence preallocation?  If not then you will not be getting any batching (check your SQL log to see if the batch is occurring).

I would not change the connection pooling defaults, your are less efficient than the default (initial 1, min 32, max 32, no separate read/write pool).  Having a different min/max will cause connection throttling, which is bad.

See,
http://java-persistence-performance.blogspot.com/2011/06/how-to-improve-jpa-performance-by-1825.html

Since JPA operates on top of JDBC, is will always take more time than fully optimized JDBC code.  But does have the advantage of letting you use Java objects and not write JDBC code, and make major optimization such as batch writing just by changing a flag, instead of rewriting the code.